# Use FactoryBoy's Maybe declaration without a "decider" model field

Tags: django, faker, factory-boy

Is it possible to use `FactoryBoy.Maybe` where the "decider" does not map to an actual model field?

Consider the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  is_heavy = models.BooleanField()
  weight = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

*This* factory works:

```
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel

  is_heavy = factory.Faker("boolean", chance_of_getting_true=50)
  weight = factory.Maybe(
    "is_heavy",
    yes_declaration=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=0, max_value="10"),
    no_declaration=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=10, max_value="20"),
  )
```

But what if I don't want the "decider" to map to an actual field of `MyModel`? Something like:

```
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel

  is_heavy = factory.Faker("boolean", chance_of_getting_true=50)
  weight = factory.Maybe(
    factory.Faker("boolean", chance_of_getting_true=50),
    yes_declaration=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=0, max_value="10"),
    no_declaration=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=10, max_value="20"),
  )
```

*That* factory doesn't work.

*(Note that it used to work prior to [this version](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/releases/tag/3.2.0) and [this PR](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/pull/828).)*

---

**edit**

Although @Xelnor's suggestion works, I'm actually writing a separate function to be used like this:

```
def optional_declaration(declaration, chance=50, default=None):

  return factory.Maybe(
    factory.Faker("boolean", chance_of_getting_true=chance),
    yes_declaration=declaration,
    no_declaration=default,
  )

class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel

  is_heavy = factory.Faker("boolean", chance_of_getting_true=50)
  weight = optional_declaration(
    factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=0, max_value="10"),
    chance=50,
    default=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=10, max_value="20"),
  )
```

so I don't have access to the factory's `Params`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do that would be to use [`class Params`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#parameters):

```py
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel

  class Params:
    is_heavy = factory.Faker("boolean", chance_of_getting_true=50)

  weight = factory.Maybe(
    "is_heavy",
    ...
  )
```

That way, users can also call `MyModelFactory(is_heavy=True)`, yet `is_heavy` will never be passed to the underlying class.

*Note: Regarding the issue you've found with "Adding a `factory.Faker` as the decider doesn't work", this looks like a bug; could you submit it to the project as an issue on github?*

Comment: submitted an issue: https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/854

Comment: Although your answer works, it doesn't really suit my use-case.  I am actually writing a separate `optional_declaration` as described in the **edited** section of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!  It never fails - the second I ask a question on StackOverflow I come up w/ a solution.

This should do the trick:

```
from functools import partial
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel

  is_heavy = factory.Faker("boolean", chance_of_getting_true=50)
  weight = factory.Maybe(
    factory.LazyFunction(partial(fake.boolean, chance_of_getting_true=50)),
    yes_declaration=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=0, max_value="10"),
    no_declaration=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=10, max_value="20"),
  )
```

*(you only need to use `partial` if you're passing variables to the faker that acts as the "decider")*